# Capybara & Rspec: How can I always test for the layout so I don't have to keep rewriting the code for it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, capybara, rspec-rails

I'm trying to stick to DRY ways of doing things with my testing. I have two layouts, `public` and `application` that show certain links and css depending on if a user is signed in or not. I'm wondering if their is a way or how I would could always test for either my public or application links and content? They use different views from my `views/shared` folder.

Here is an example of a test for my Welcome Page which is public:

spec/requests/pages_spec.rb

```
describe 'Pages' do

  describe 'Welcome Page' do

    before { visit root_path }
    response.should render_template("layouts/public")

    it 'should have public footer present' do
      find_link('Home').visible?
      find_link('Login').visible?
      find_link('Help').visible?
    end
  end

end
```

Now the public footer is apart of the public layout and I have more code that belongs to this layout. My goal is to write this only once and put it inside of some method and use it for the pages/test I need it for. How would I do this? I don't want to write to see if the appropriate layout with its content is being used in every single test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to remember that RSpec is just Ruby, or more specifically it's a [DSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) written in Ruby targeted at testing.

So, just define a method.

```
describe 'Pages' do

  describe 'Welcome Page' do

    before { visit root_path }
    response.should render_template("layouts/public")

    it 'should have public footer present' do
      links_are_visible?.should be true
    end

    # Call this wherever, whenever you need it
    def links_are_visible?
      find_link('Home').visible? && find_link('Login').visible && find_link('Help').visible?
    end
  end

end
```

You can also do shared examples and other things outlined in this article: http://testdrivenwebsites.com/2011/08/17/different-ways-of-code-reuse-in-rspec/